# Convert a JavaScript statement to a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array in a variable like:

`arr = [1, 2, 3]`

How can I convert that statement to a string that it will be:

`newArr = "arr = [1, 2, 3]"`

Comment: they array elements to a string you can use arrays join() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

const str = `${Object.keys({arr})} = ${JSON.stringify(arr)}`;

console.log(str);
```

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

I would use this `JSON.Stringify()`.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

If you mean it literally, you can do:

```
const infoArray = [1, 2, 3];
const newArray = `infoArray = [` + infoArray.join(',') + "]";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3];
const newArr = `arr = [${arr.toString()}]`;
console.log(newArr);

//And A more Dynamic  Solution would be:

console.log(`${Object.keys({arr})} = [${arr.toString()}]`);
```

Comment: and when the name of the array is not arr?

Comment: Hmmm :) A more Dynamic solution you mean.. Let me see if there is a way to get property name :)

Comment: I thought that the dynamic solution is what the OP want

Comment: Well !!! That's also possible !!! Trying to figure out...

Comment: @Alex: This would do it .Check my updated answer ..console.log(`${Object.keys({arr})} = [${arr.toString()}]`);

Comment: this doesn't work with string values in array. Eg: ```arr = [1, 2, 3, "a"]```. Expected output is ```[1, 2, 3, "a"]``` but it gives ```[1, 2, 3, a]```

Comment: Even this does not work with string values const str = `${Object.keys({arr})} = ${JSON.stringify(arr)}`;

Comment: What about other Data Types like Objects :) We can have any kind of data types in our Array >>> Say for example: const arr = [1,2,3,"a",{x:"1",y:{a:2}}]; or more complex arrays which have functions within... Your Question should also have included all the scenarios...Even JSON.stringify() fails for complex types...As per your Question people have answered...

Answer (score 0):

```
newArr = "arr = [" + String(arr) + "]"
```

Comment: and when the name of the arr is not arr?

Comment: Change message it in the string.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as a function then call the only function by declaration.

```
const temp =  () => {
  arr = [1, 2, 3]
}
const src = temp.toString()
newArr = src.slice(9, src.length).slice(0, src.length - 1)
```

Above codes result on .toString() '() => {\n arr = [1,2,3]}' then we use .slice to cut out not needed parts.